# Vagrant guest not getting assigned correct IP

Tags: networking, vagrant

My Vagrantfile contains the line `config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"` but when the machine comes up `ifconfig` shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1B:06:06  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1b:606/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:92471 (90.3 KiB)  TX bytes:97079 (94.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:40178 (39.2 KiB)  TX bytes:40178 (39.2 KiB)
```

So the guest is getting assigned an IP from a totally different range.  The results of `ifconfig` on the host show:

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:1b:0d:3b:06:a0  
          inet addr:10.100.102.10  Bcast:10.100.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::89fb:6606:8d85:ba21/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:214746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124683 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:295158044 (295.1 MB)  TX bytes:10146317 (10.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:35183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:4777700 (4.7 MB)  TX bytes:4777700 (4.7 MB)

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.33.1  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:188146 (188.1 KB)
```

Any ideas on how to get vagrant to assign the correct IP? (This is vagrant 1.9.1, host is Ubuntu 16, guest is CentOS 6.

**Edit**: this is the output of `vagrant up`:

```
$ vagrant up dev
Bringing machine 'dev' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> dev: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> dev: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> dev: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    dev: Adapter 1: nat
    dev: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> dev: Forwarding ports...
    dev: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> dev: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> dev: Booting VM...
==> dev: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    dev: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    dev: SSH username: vagrant
    dev: SSH auth method: private key
==> dev: Machine booted and ready!
==> dev: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    dev: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    dev: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    dev: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    dev: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    dev: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    dev: your host and reload your VM.
    dev: 
    dev: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.26
    dev: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> dev: Setting hostname...
==> dev: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> dev: Mounting shared folders...
    dev: /vagrant => /home/johnny/dev/lumify
    dev: /home/vagrant/.m2 => /home/johnny/.m2
==> dev: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> dev: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Comment: whats the output of `vagrant up` command ? its weird as you should have a second network interface with the right IP (it will show only in the guest not the host)

Comment: I've added the output of `vagrant up`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some testing I just did, I think the answer here is to upgrade to Vagrant 1.9.2. I actually had not noticed this before because I mostly use Ubuntu boxes, but with a CentOS 7.2 guest VM I'm getting the same result you did. I'm defining a private network as follows:

```
x.vm.network :private_network, ip: 10.211.54.5
```

After `vagrant up`, login to the box and check the output of `ifconfig`:

Before (Vagrant 1.9.1, VirtualBox 5.0.30r112061, Mac host 10.11.6)

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea3:aab6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:a3:aa:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 40213  bytes 49148144 (46.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10192  bytes 647080 (631.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

After (upgrade Vagrant to 1.9.2):

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea3:aab6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:a3:aa:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 41483  bytes 49218539 (46.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10982  bytes 694063 (677.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.211.54.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.211.54.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe25:5f05  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:25:5f:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 846 (846.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23  bytes 2538 (2.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I searched Vagrant changelog and issues and could not pin down the exact change, but there were several that mentioned network-related fixes for Redhat/CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like active development of Lumify's open source version ended in 2015. Have you tried the [open source version of Visallo](http://docs.visallo.org)? There's also an [enterprise edition](https://www.visallo.com) if you need additional capabilities or greater scalability.